# Converting Date/Time Text to Date/Time Values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am having a small issue in Excel 2010, I have a column with date/time values in plain text, I wish to convert them to date/time values and add on one year.

Example : 14/10/2011  03:49:00 to 14/10/2012  03:49:00

I have this working for converting the date but not the time... Here is my code

```
=DATE(RIGHT(AB22,4)+1,MID(AB22,4,2),LEFT(AB22,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel should calculate as a date, even if stored as text

Try:

```
=DATE(YEAR(AB22)+1,MONTH(AB22),DAY(AB22)) + TIME(HOUR(AB22),MINUTE(AB22),SECOND(AB22))
```

Then use a custom format to display the full datetime:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: Hey Shevek, I tried your code just now and Excel told me I used too many arguments for this function.

Thanks for your reply all the same.

Comment: Actually, apologies Shevek... That worked perfectly. Thanks